# Connectivity plot of points

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I am new to programming and I got a question that asked me to draw a connectivity plot of point from the 2 lists given. My logic was to keep a single coordinate constant while plotting the other in a for loop but this did not work... please help

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def Question_3():

   x = [0, 0.7, 1, 0.7, 0, -0.7, -1, -0.7]
   y = [1, 0.7, 0, -0.7, -1, -0.7, 0, 0.7]

   plt.subplot(121)
   plt.title("Scatter plot of points", fontsize = 16)
   plt.plot(x, y, ".k")
   plt.show()

   plt.subplot(122)
   plt.title("Connectivity plot of points", fontsize = 16)

   for C1 in zip(x, y):
      for C2 in zip(x, y):            
          plt.plot(C1, C2, "-r")      

   plt.show()
Question_3()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose by connectivity plot you mean a plot that connects every point with every other point.

In that sense the approach you took is correct; just mind that `plt.plot(x,y)` has a list or sequence of the x-coordinates as first argument and one for the y coordinate as second argument. You would therefore need to unpack and split the variables from the two loops into their x- and y component.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def Question_3():

   x = [0, 0.7, 1, 0.7, 0, -0.7, -1, -0.7]
   y = [1, 0.7, 0, -0.7, -1, -0.7, 0, 0.7]

   plt.subplot(121)
   plt.title("Scatter plot of points", fontsize = 16)
   plt.plot(x, y, ".k")


   plt.subplot(122)
   plt.title("Connectivity plot of points", fontsize = 16)

   for x0,y0 in zip(x, y):
      for x1,y1 in zip(x, y):            
          plt.plot((x0,x1), (y0,y1), "-r")      

   plt.show()
Question_3()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! i have tried that but i used `plt.plot((x0,y0), (x1,y1), "-r")`.